# Find most common pairs across multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Client   1_act      2_act      3_act      4_act      5_act      6_act   ...
1        hiking     swimming   skating    jumping    climbing   eating
2        eating     hiking     climbing   exploring  
3        hiking     exercising 
4        hiking     screaming  yelling    hopping    swimming  
...
```

Every row only has unique activities and can have MANY columns all named #_act (new columns can also be added at any time as a client reports a new activity). Every row has at least a pair (no one has less than 2 activities per row). New activity values can also be added at any time.

I am trying to find a way to return the most common pair of activity. So desired output would be like:

```
Pair                       Qty
(hiking, swimming)         2
(hiking, skating)          1
(hiking, jumping)          1
(hiking, climbing)         2
(hiking, eating)           2
(swimming, skating)        1
(swimming, jumping)        1
(swimming, climbing)       1
(swimming, eating)         1
(skating, jumping)         1
(skating, climbing)        1
(skating, eating)          1
(jumping, climbing)        1
(climbing, eating)         2
(eating, exploring)        1
(hiking, exercising)       1
(hiking, screaming)        1
(hiking, yelling)          1
(hiking, hopping)          1

...
```

The above output is an example output of all possible pairs in each row across all their columns in this sample dataset. If a pair repeated in subsequent rows it should add to the quantity, and if a new pair occurs in subsequent rows, it should be added to the column of pairs as a new row.

The purpose of this is to see what pair of activities are the most common among all clients. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `combinations` in list comprehension for flattening, count tuples by `Counter` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from collections import Counter
from  itertools import combinations

df = df.set_index('Client')

c = Counter([y for x in df.values for y in combinations(x, 2)])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pair': list(c.keys()), 'Qty': list(c.values())})
```

For top combinations:

```
n = 10
L = Counter([y for x in df.values for y in combinations(x, 2)]).most_common(n)

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Pair', 'Qty'])
print (df)
                   Pair  Qty
0    (hiking, swimming)    2
1    (hiking, climbing)    2
2      (hiking, eating)    2
3    (swimming, eating)    2
4     (hiking, hopping)    2
5     (hiking, skating)    1
6     (hiking, jumping)    1
7   (swimming, skating)    1
8   (swimming, jumping)    1
9  (swimming, climbing)    1
```

Comment: This is amazing! I was trying to do this all in pandas without importing anything, but this does the trick! That's probably why I've been so stumped! My only question is when I tried it, it also includes "None" values as a pair, so like (hiking, None) -- is there a way to have it only consider non-null values as eligible to be in a pair? Thank you!

Comment: @Chrestomanci - Change `combinations(x, 2)` to `combinations([z for z in x if z == z], 2)`

Comment: The None seems to persist with that change, but I just removed all rows with None in them after the fact. Not sure if that's the most efficient way, but it worked!

Comment: @Chrestomanci You are right, my solution with `z == z` remove `NAN`s, for remove Nones need `[z for z in x if z]`

Comment: That's BRILLIANT! It worked, thank you! Saved me 2 extra lines to remove them after the fact!

Comment: Darn, I just found an issue where if the value occurs in the reverse direction, it isn't counted -- for example, if a row has hiking & swimming, then the pair (hiking, swimming) will not count if another row has swimming & hiking in reverse. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @Chrestomanci - Is possible create new question with new data for see this problem and expected output? thanks.