# Creating a plot with the most occurring combinations of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, list-comprehension

For showing my data I want to create a frequency plot. This plot will be based on the number of times a combination between two columns occur. I have a two columns in a dataset (df):

`acq_cc: [CN, IN, CN, CN, CN, IN, CN, CN, CN, ZA]`

`tar_cc: [GB, ZA, NO, AR, VG, JP, NL, PK, PK, SG]`

The value of the columns needs to be combined e.g. CN - GB, IN - ZA. Afterwards, I want to count how often a combination of occurs. In this situation  CN - PK occurs twice.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229758/find-most-common-pairs-across-multiple-columns) example but since I have no 'Client' value, I receive an error code. The final frequency plot should show a combination of the top 10 most combinations (on the x-axis) and their counts (on the y-axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `value_counts` on multiple columns then use `head` to select top 10 most occurring combinations:

```
c = ['acq_cc', 'tar_cc']
df[c].value_counts().head(10).plot(kind='bar')
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I receive the following error message: `Boolean array expected for the condition, not object` . I guess this has something to do with the fact that tar_cc and acq_cc are generated from a bigger dataset: `c = df[[ 'acq_cc', 'tar_cc']]` Do you know a solution?

Comment: @pangelbird The value of variable `c` should be equal to the list of column names as shown in the solution. `c = ['acq_cc', 'tar_cc']`

Comment: One last question, is there a easy way to give all the different combinations/bars a unique color?

Comment: You can pass the `color` parameter to the plot method: `.plot(kind='bar', color=list('rgbkymc'))` or  `.plot(kind='bar', color=['red', 'green', 'blue',  ...])`

Comment: Is there a easy way to save this plot at a high quality?